# Is there a way in Python GitHub library to check if the branch for which a PR has been raised is out-of-date from it's base branch or not?

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

- My python script is getting a list of PRs and then it needs to run a check if the branches being used in those PRs are out-of-date from their base branch or not.
- I need to perform this action remotely i.e without cloning the repo to my local machine.

[image]

- The image attached shows what we see in the GUI if we go to the PR manually.
- My script searches for PRs (that have the string: DEVELOPERS-XXXX). Once I have the paginated list, it uses them one by one:

```
    from github import Github

    github_t = os.environ.get('GITHUB_TOKEN')
    github_c = Github(github_t)
    git_i = github_c.search_issues('DEVELOPERS-XXXX', state='open')
    for search in git_i:
```

- I am unable to find an attribute that can help me check if the branch used in the PR is out-of-date from it's base branch.

Answer (score 0):

- Since I could not find the attribute to resolve my query, I used a gh bash command to get past my issue:

```
result = subprocess.run(['gh', 'pr', 'view', fun_search_pr.html_url, '--json', 'mergeStateStatus'], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

- If the result shows BEHIND, it means that the head ref is out of date:

```
{
  "mergeStateStatus": "BEHIND"
}
```

- The above interpretation is as per the following documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#mergestatestatus